# How to open an existing view but disabling its create button in Odoo?

Tags: xml, odoo

I have a One2many field, which is showing the tree view with the highest priority of its comodel. Actually I want to show that tree view, but with create mode disabled (to avoid users to add items).

So I was wondering if there is any way to do that without calling a replica of the whole tree view only to add the attribute `create="false"` to the `tree` tag.

I think that adding another record to the `ir_ui_view` only for that is a bit repetitive and not very functional.

Does anyone use a better method?

**EDIT**

I am editing this to be clearer since every answer is proposing the same. The following code is not a solution for my question:

```
<field name="one2many_field">
   <tree create="false">
      <field name="field_x"/>
      <field name="field_y"/>
      ...
   </tree>
</field>
```

In this case I have to copy all the fields of the existing tree view into the `tree` tag. I am trying to avoid that for several reasons:

1. I want to re-use existing code if it is possible.
2. The tree view could have (like in my case) a lot of fields added in different modules. I should have to modify the `depends` parameter of the `__manifest__.py` of my custom module to include all the modules which insert those fields. However, my module does not depend on those modules at all, I would have to do that only to replicate the tree view.
3. Due to the point 2, if a module which add fields to the source tree view is installed after my module, those new fields will not be shown in my tree view (the one with `create="false"`).

So I ask if someone knows a way to use an existing view (not paste its fields inside a `tree` tag) but disabling its *Create* option.

Comment: No easy way to do it. I think copying is more easy

Comment: @EasyOdoo I figured that out, but I wanted to ask just in case, to keep improving if someone gave me an affordable solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting question. I actually didn't know if this could be done, but you can achieve it with a combination of `tree_view_ref`, view `mode` and `priority`.

## Solution

I created a couple of simple addons (`custom_sale` and `test_addon`) to test this. The first one just adds a new field to one of the `sale.order` tree views. I did this to make sure the other module shows the new field too in the `One2many`.

### custom_sale:

**sale_order.py**

```
from odoo import fields, models


class SaleOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'

    dummy_field = fields.Char(String="Dummy")
```

**sale_order_views.xml**

```
<odoo>

    <record id="view_quotation_tree_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">view_quotation_tree_inherit</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_quotation_tree"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="state" position="after">
                <field name="dummy_field"/>
            </field>
        </field>
    </record>

</odoo>
```

### test_addon:

**dummy_model.py**

```
from odoo import fields, models


class Dummy(models.Model):
    _name = 'dummy.model'

    name = fields.Char()
    order_ids = fields.One2many(
        comodel_name='sale.order',
        inverse_name='dummy_id'
    )
```

**sale_order.py**

```
from odoo import fields, models


class Order(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'

    dummy_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='dummy.model')
```

Nothing fancy so far. All the magic happens on the views. First, we have to inherit the tree view of the model our `One2many` field points to: in my case, `sale.order`. We have to make sure the new view's `mode` is `primary`. And we set a high enough priority to ensure that the fields added by other modules we don't depend on also appear in our view (I think priority can go as high as 9999, not sure though). Of course, we also add the `create="false"` attribute to the `tree` node.

**sale_order_views.xml**

```
<odoo>

    <record id="view_quotation_tree_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">view_quotation_tree_inherit</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="mode">primary</field>
        <field name="priority" eval="500"/>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_quotation_tree"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree position="attributes">
                <attribute name="create">0</attribute>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>

</odoo>
```

And, on the `dummy.model` form view, when we declare the `order_ids` field, we have to pass our view via context with `tree_view_ref` key (you might also want to check `form_view_ref`). I also added a simple action and some menu items so I could test everything.

**dummy_model_views.xml**

```
    <record id="dummy_view_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">dummy_view_tree</field>
        <field name="model">dummy.model</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree>
                <field name="name"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="dummy_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">dummy_view_form</field>
        <field name="model">dummy.model</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form>
                <group>
                    <field name="name"/>
                </group>
                <field name="order_ids"
                       context="{'tree_view_ref': 'test_addon.view_quotation_tree_inherit'}"/>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_dummy_tree">
        <field name="name">Dummy List</field>
        <field name="res_model">dummy.model</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="context">{}</field>
    </record>

    <menuitem name="Dummy" id="menu_dummy" sequence="70"/>
        <menuitem name="Dummy List" id="menu_dummy_list" sequence="5" parent="menu_dummy" action="action_dummy_tree"/>

</odoo>
```

Note that, in my `test_addon`, I did not have any way to fill the O2m field (I guess you are doing it programatically or that they are created in some other way), so I enabled and disabled creation on the tree view in order to create some records and test if I was able to edit and delete them. By the way, I'm quite sure this should also work for `Many2many` fields.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Very good solution @jzeta. I did not come up with that idea despite I did know about context key `tree_view_ref`, `mode primary` and `priority`. Kudos to you ;)

Comment: Wow @jzeta I have been working with Odoo for two years I didn't see this mode primary Thanks for the info I duplicated a lot of codes before thanks to you and forvas I will never do that again LOL

Answer (score 0):

The `create="false"` attribute on the `<tree>` tag will do the trick, so why don't you inherit your view and change the attributes of the `<tree>` tag.

```
<template id="your_view_id" inherit_id="some_module.some_view_id" name="Your View" priority="50">
    <xpath expr="//tree" position="attributes">
        <attribute name="create" eval="False"/>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

The following example will show a tree view on which the one-to-many relationship is read-only

```
<field name="one_to_many_field_ids">
    <tree create="false">
        <field name="name"/>
    </tree>
</field>
```

Comment: If I do that I will modify the tree in every part of Odoo, I would like to use the existing view without modifying it permanently. I am looking for a solution to avoid copying all the fields inside a tree inside my One2many field.

Comment: May be there is no way to do it (unless I modify the Odoo core), just asking if someone does something different and more efficient to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

The `readonly="1"` attribute applied to the One2many field.

It's used on the view `view_move_form` on `<path_to_v12>/addons/stock/views/stock_move_views.xml` like so:

```
<field name="move_orig_ids" string="Origin Moves" readonly="1">
    <tree>
        <field name="location_id"/>
        <field name="location_dest_id"/>
        <field name="product_uom_qty"/>
        <field name="product_uom"/>
        <field name="state"/>
    </tree>
</field>
```

So, maybe `<field name="one2many_field_ids" readonly="1"/>` will suffice.

Comment: Thank you, but that would make the whole tree readonly, I only want to disable creation, not edit nor deletion. Besides, in this case you are still creating the view again, not using the existing one, since you insert fields into the `tree` tag inside the One2many field.

Comment: You are right, this solution will disable edit and deletion too. However, if the `<tree>` is not explicitly given, Odoo should look for the view with the highest priority. Sorry, I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Try this . It will disable the button

```
<tree string="Sim Tree" create="false" >
```

Comment: This solution is not what I am asking for. I have edited my question to be more specific and explain the reason why not.